# Polytope parametrization

Tags: computational-geometry, polytopes

How one could parametrize a convex polytope?

By parametrization I mean something like in multiple integrals, when to integrate over an area one can integrate over one variable in an interval $[l,r]$ and inside over other in $[l(x),r(x)]$

More formally, how one could take a convex polytope (in H- or V-representation, does not matter to me) and describe it in H-representation as
$$
l_1 \le x_1 \le r_1 \\
l_2(x_1) \le x_2 \le r_2(x_1) \\
\ldots \\
l_d(x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1}) \le x_d \le r_d(x_1,\ldots,x_{d-1})
$$

Since not every polytope can be represented in that way, I'm also interested in a way to split a polytope to many that can.

Comment: Are the polytopes convex?

Comment: Yes, convex. Thanks @BrianRushton , fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard: computing the volume of a convex polytope is $\#P$ hard. For various related issues , heuristics, and occasional algorithms, see this nice presentation by [Jesus de Loera.](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/TEACHING/RMMC2011/volumes_integrals.pdf)

Comment: Computing volume of simplex is as hard as matrix determinant. Delaunay triangulation, in nondegenerate case, can be done with reverse search. So, for non-degenerate polytope volume can be effectively computed, am I right?

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov what do you mean by "effectively computed"? There are algorithms, but they are exponential in the input.

Comment: well, I mean that convex hull algorithm that is polynomial in number of vertices for fixed dimension is considered effective.

Comment: @MikhailCheshkov that's fine (though I would hate to actually use one of these effective algorithms in 20 dimensions), but it is an indication that there is no easy answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for 3D space; I don't know if/how it generalizes.

Basically, you can choose some arbitrary origin, and decompose the given polyhedron into a collection of pyramidal volumes that each have this origin point as apex.

Then, you can get the volume of the original polytope by adding together the (signed) volumes of these pyramidal volumes.

There's a document here, http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/PolyhedralMassProperties.pdf, and the same web site has C++ code to do the calculations. None of this requires the kind of parameterization you mentioned.

Comment: Volume is not in question, the functions l_i, r_i is.